# i want my firebase realtime database to ONLY accept new data that is +1 more than current data. current code not working as expected

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

for security I want this points data to ONLY be able to increase by 1. no more.

technically I want the points to save if the data is as follows:
points = 1 on app and in database ACCEPT DATA. or. points = 2 on app and 1 in database ACCEPT AND UPDATE.
anything else , NO.

I don't want somebody to change my app scripts and say: "hey , lets make it give me 1000 points instead of 1.

This is the Rules I am using that isn't giving me the result I want:

```json
    "points": {
      // asserts points is a number and is correctly increased by 1
      ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && ((data.val() == null && newData.val() == 1) || 
                    data.val() == data.val() || newData.val() === data.val() + 1 && 
                    newData.val() > data.val() && newData.val() < data.val() +2)",},
```

Answer (score 2):

```json
".validate": "data.val() == newData.val() || (newData.isNumber() && ((data.val() == null && newData.val() == 1) || newData.val() === data.val() + 1))"
```

Comment: HOLLY DAMN im a dumby dumd. THANKS MAN! you're a damn beast. i have been struggling for for 2 days now with security rules. Thanks a lot! saved me from going insane. Now i can finally finish up my damn App :D

Comment: @EricShare If this solved your problem, don't forget to [mark it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).